# PHPUnit Test case randomly fails with undefined index and Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

A test case in my PHP/Laravel App randomly fails. Looks like it has its own life.

The test case fails with the following errors:

```
Undefined index: impressions
```

and

```
Trying to get property 'ad' of non-object
```

The file tested:

```
    class AdReportController extends Controller
{
    /** @var CampaignGroupRepository */
    private $campaignGroupRepo;

    /** @var AdWordsAccountRepository */
    private $adWordsAccountRepo;

    /** @var AdReportRepository */
    private $adReportRepo;

    public function __construct(
        CampaignGroupRepository $campaignGroupRepo,
        AdWordsAccountRepository $adWordsAccountRepo,
        AdReportRepository $adReportRepo
    ) {
        $this->campaignGroupRepo  = $campaignGroupRepo;
        $this->adReportRepo       = $adReportRepo;
        $this->adWordsAccountRepo = $adWordsAccountRepo;

        $this->setTransformer(new AdReportTransformer());
    }

    public function top(AdReportsRequest $request, int $accountId): JsonResponse
    {
        $campaignGroup = $request->input('campaign_group');
        $dateFrom      = $request->input('from');
        $dateTo        = $request->input('to');

        $adWordsAccount = $this->adWordsAccountRepo->findOrFailByGoogleId($accountId);
        $campaignGroup  = $this->campaignGroupRepo->findOrFail($campaignGroup, $adWordsAccount);

        $report = $this->adReportRepo->top($campaignGroup, $dateFrom, $dateTo);

        return $this->response($report);
    }
}
```

Test case for the impression error:

```
public function testIgnoreReportsFromOtherCampaignGroups(): void
{
    [$account, $campaignGroup, $ad] = $this->createEverything();

    $top = $this->createAdReport([
        'date'             => '2019-01-01',
        'ad'               => $ad,
        'impressions'      => 100,
        'clickThroughRate' => 100,
    ]);

    [, , $ad2] = $this->createEverything($account);

    $this->createAdReport([
        'date'             => '2019-01-01',
        'ad'               => $ad2,
        'impressions'      => 300,
        'clickThroughRate' => 150,
    ]);

    $params = http_build_query([
        'campaign_group' => $campaignGroup->id,
        'from'           => '2018-12-30',
        'to'             => '2019-01-06',
    ]);

    $remote = $this->callIt($account, $params)->json();

    $this->assertSame($remote['impressions'], $top->impressions);
}
```

Test case for the other error:

```
public function testIgnoreReportsFromOtherAccounts(): void
    {
        [$account, $campaignGroup, $ad] = $this->createEverything();

        $top = $this->createAdReport([
            'date'             => '2019-01-01',
            'ad'               => $ad,
            'impressions'      => 100,
            'clickThroughRate' => 100,
        ]);

        [, , $ad2] = $this->createEverything();

        $this->createAdReport([
            'date'             => '2019-01-01',
            'ad'               => $ad2,
            'impressions'      => 300,
            'clickThroughRate' => 150,
        ]);

        $params = http_build_query([
            'campaign_group' => $campaignGroup->id,
            'from'           => '2018-12-30',
            'to'             => '2019-01-06',
        ]);

        $remote = $this->callIt($account, $params)->json();

        $this->assertSame($remote['impressions'], $top->impressions);
    }
```

Cannot figure out why those tests are failing and randomly.I can run 20 times no fail then a fail.

Comment: generate a var_dump of $remote and check what are you returning...

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing that may be useful for someone else. 
The issue was that the method was generating randomly some reports for the Ads with a specific index. But from last commits those values have been changed so when the random report was generated below an index of 5 or much more above that cause the issues.

The solution was to add `'clicks' => 10,` and as the example below:

```
$top = $this->createAdReport([
            'date'             => '2019-01-01',
            'ad'               => $ad,
            'impressions'      => 100,
            'clickThroughRate' => 20,
            'clicks'           => 10,
        ]);
```